# Changing Encryption Key for Azure Data Lake Store

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-keyvault

I have an Azure Data Lake Store that is encrypted with an user managed key. I need to get rid of the Key-Vault that holds this key and create a new one. How can I change the encryption key setting in ADLS to use from new Key-Vault.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to get rid of the Key-Vault that holds this key and create a new one. How can I change the encryption key setting in ADLS to use from new Key-Vault.

**Unfortuntly**, short answer is **no**. We could get it from [azure Encryption of data in Azure Data Lake Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-encryption#key-rotation).

> Note that Data Lake Store currently only supports key rotation to a new version of a key. It **doesn't support** rotating to a **different** key.